# How to use DNU WRAP for projects NOT in a solution with ASP.Net projects

Tags: .net-assembly, asp.net-core, csproj

After much searching and following bread crumbs, it appears that to add a NON ASP.NET assembly as a reference to a ASP.Net project (not in the same solution), one must use DNU WRAP.

I attempted to do so by doing a CD to the solution directory and entering the following line

```
dnu -v wrap --configuration release -i code/access/access.csproj
```

The response tells me that I am missing NuGet packages and to 'enable NuGet Package Restore'.  I had (and rechecked) already done so.

Searching the internet for 'dnu wrap' returned 2 hits on GitHub with the more [interesting one being](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/pull/1738) a side discussion of dnu wrap needing a global.json at the solution level.  However, my one ASP.Net solution does NOT have a global.json file.

My questions are
1) what are the steps required to get dnu wrap to work correctly on a Windows system with VS 2015 RC installed?
2) under what conditions must the dnu wrap be redone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add references to locally created NON ASP.Net 5 dlls to an ASP.Net 5 project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970854/how-do-you-add-references-to-locally-created-non-asp-net-5-dlls-to-an-asp-net-5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the process.  It has changed over the past 10 months since I started on the journey.

See [my answer to my question on how to wrap a dll for reference in a asp.net project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970854/how-do-you-add-references-to-locally-created-non-asp-net-5-dlls-to-an-asp-net-5) for a lengthy response.

Comment: Correct action in that case: close/dup this question.