# DNX does not work

Tags: dnx

I have installed dnvm successfully on windows server 2008. 
but when I run "dnx", nothing shown. no error message like this:

C:\Windows\system32\dnx 
C:\Windows\system32\

someone had the same problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you need to understand structure of DNX. By default it's installed in `%USERPROFILE%\.dnx`. Inside of it you should find `runtimes` folder containing all of installed CLRs e.g.

- dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta4
- dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6-11938

Each of them has its own `bin` folder with `dnx.exe` and `dnu.cmd`. These are the ones you are looking for. So basically after executing `dnvm upgrade` (as suggested by @tugberk) DNVM installs latest DNX from feed, marks it as default and adds it to user's PATH variable. Your PATH might has not been updated for some reason and I suggest you do it manually by including path to your desired CLR version.

It is also possible to install CLR to machine-wide location by adding `-g` flag.

After try to run: `C:\>dnx`

Output:

```
Microsoft .NET Execution environment CLR-x86-1.0.0-beta6-11938
Usage: dnx [options] ...
```

Detailed documentation on DNVM - **[ASP.NET Home / Version Manager](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Version-Manager)**

Answer (score 3):

Installing DNVM doesn't mean you also installed DNX. Run the following command the get the latest stable release:

```
dnvm upgrade
```

Then you should be able to run `dnx` and `dnu`.

Comment: I had tried.not working. dnx does not work after running "dnvm upgrade"

Answer (score 0):

You can run different versions of dnvm simultaneously on the same machine, so the installer doesn't set the value for dnx in the user's PATH variable as part of the install because, if you already had another version of dnvm installed, that could lead to unexpected results for anything using the existing version.

If you want to see what's going, then do the following (paraphrasing from [another answer I wrote on this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30440974/dnx-command-not-found-in-developer-command-prompt-for-vs2015/34788655#34788655)):

first do:

```
dnvm upgrade
```

This gets the most up to date version of dnvm and sets it as the default for that command prompt session.

Then you can list out all the versions of ASP.NET 5 installed on your machine as follows:

```
dnvm list
```

You can then set one of the items in that list as the default with e.g. (NB: the actual version may be different depending on when you view this answer):

```
dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-update1 -r clr -arch x64 -p
```

The `-p` on the end means 'persist' and that is the setting that will then persist the default you just selected to both the process (session) PATH and also the user PATH variable. Persisting to the user PATH means the default is then available everywhere.

If you leave off the `-p` then you can select a version just for use in that command prompt session.

After that you should be able to use `dnx` as expected.