# Reference a native dll from an asp.net 5 project

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, .net, dll

I am trying to reference a native dll from an asp.net 5 project using pinvoke. The recommended solution is to wrap the dll in a nuget package and reference that. However I am also developing the native dll, so it is impractical to constantly create new nuget packages when I make changes.

If I have the native dll location in the path variable it is found through pinvoke and works fine. But I would like a solution which is contained in the Visual Studio solution so that other developers could download the VS solution and have it work without changing the path variable.

I tried using the bin syntax as described in this topic:

[How do you add references to locally created NON ASP.Net 5 dlls to an ASP.Net 5 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970854/how-do-you-add-references-to-locally-created-non-asp-net-5-dlls-to-an-asp-net-5/29975503#29975503)

but that seems to only work for managed assemblies as I get an error stating that the assembly manifest cannot be found.

Thanks